# Python Web Scrape: Remove excess HTML tags in output. All data are from a page table, get_text and pretiffy doesnt work

Tags: python, web-scraping

Newbie here. I am just practicing python all by my self.

My problem is this:

I am web scraping this ramdom site and i wanted to get the filename and the filedate and print them together. But excess html tags is still there and i cant get rid of them even if i am using get_text and prettify. Sorry noob question. Just needed help. Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://1337x.to/popular-tv').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

tvhead = soup.find('tbody')
for tv in tvhead.find_all('tr'):
    filename = tv.find_all('td' , class_='coll-1 name')
    filedate = tv.find_all('td', class_='coll-date')
    print(filename)
    print(filedate)
    print()
```

output is this:

```
[<td class="coll-1 name"><a class="icon" href="/sub/41/0/"><i class="flaticon-hd"></i></a><a href="/torrent/3225547/Castle-Rock-S01E10-Romans-720p-HULU-WEB-DL-AAC2-0-H-264-NTb-eztv/">Castle.Rock.S01E10.Romans.720p.HULU.WEB-DL.AAC2.0.H.264-NTb[eztv]</a></td>]
[<td class="coll-date">7am Sep. 12th</td>]

[<td class="coll-1 name"><a class="icon" href="/sub/6/0/"><i class="flaticon-divx"></i></a><a href="/torrent/3225539/Castle-Rock-S01E10-Romans-480p-HULU-WEB-DL-AAC2-0-H-264-BTW-ettv/">Castle.Rock.S01E10.Romans.480p.HULU.WEB-DL.AAC2.0.H.264-BTW[ettv]</a></td>]
[<td class="coll-date">7am Sep. 12th</td>]

[<td class="coll-1 name"><a class="icon" href="/sub/6/0/"><i class="flaticon-divx"></i></a><a href="/torrent/3225653/The-Outpost-S01E08-WEB-h264-TBS-ettv/">The.Outpost.S01E08.WEB.h264-TBS[ettv]</a></td>]
[<td class="coll-date">9am Sep. 12th</td>]
```

Expected output should be just the title and the date like:

```
TV Series title
Date
```

Comment: can you add your current output and your expected output?

Comment: Did you try scrapy ? https://scrapy.org/

Comment: sorry no, i have not. will try it now.

Comment: I personally had a good experience using it for this kind of projects. If that fits, perhaps it can help you organize your code and scale it when it's ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://1337x.to/popular-tv').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

tvhead = soup.find('tbody')
for tv in tvhead.find_all('tr'):
    filename = tv.find_all('td' , class_='coll-1 name')
    filedate = tv.find_all('td', class_='coll-date')
    print(filename[0].text)
    print(filedate[0].text)
    print()
```

Comment: I got these error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/R/Pycharm/W3PythonPractise/Scarapenew.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(filename.get_text())
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1884, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

Comment: Here you go. Imagination coding is hard. Had to run it myself.

Comment: Thanks. Its working. just learn a new way to clean the data. Thank you again.